# Как округлить время в большую сторону до получаса Python?

Tags: python, время, datetime

Как я могу округлить время в большую сторону до получаса в Python?

Пример выполнения:

```
now = datetime.datetime.now() # 2020-11-14 15:13:32.249588

rounded_time = roundtime(now) # 2020-11-14 15:30:00.000000
```

Comment: показывайте свою реализацию...

Comment: @Jack_oS вопрос не об отладке, и он достаточно прямолинеен, авторский код тут не обязателен.

Answer (score 1):

Округлите время до 30 минут и, если надо, прибавьте час

```
import datetime
import math

now = datetime.datetime.now()
hours, minutes = divmod(math.ceil(now.minute/30)*30, 60);
rounded_time = (now + datetime.timedelta(hours=hours)).replace(minute=minutes);
```